# Using a pandas dataframe how to aggregate and groupby and bring in non aggregated/groupby columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'month': pd.Series(['jan', 'jan', 'feb', 'feb']),
     'week' : pd.Series(['wk1', 'wk2', 'wk1', 'wk2']),
     'high_temp' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 20]), 
     'low_temp' : pd.Series([4, 5, 23, 40])} 

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    high_temp  low_temp month week
0         10         4   jan  wk1
1         20         5   jan  wk2
2         30        23   feb  wk1
3         20        40   feb  wk2
```

I would like to get is a new dataframe with this data

```
    month    high_temp   high_temp_week  low_temp  low_temp_week
0   Jan         20            wk2           4          wk1
1   Feb         30            wk1           23         wk1
```

I can easily get the max of the temps grouped by month but I can't figure out how to bring along the week column from the row with the max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) depending on the case, [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and keep last of first, then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). You do the merge only on month and you specify suffixes to rename the column week that is in both dataframe.

```
new_df = df[['month', 'high_temp', 'week']].sort_values('high_temp').drop_duplicates('month', keep='last')\
            .merge(df[['month', 'low_temp', 'week']].sort_values('low_temp').drop_duplicates('month', keep='first'), 
                   on='month', suffixes=('_high_temp', '_low_temp'))

print (new_df)
  month  high_temp week_high_temp  low_temp week_low_temp
0   jan         20            wk2         4           wk1
1   feb         30            wk1        23           wk1
```

Comment: I actually started with YOBEN_S style first since they are the same basic solution.  His is easier while developing but once I had all the pieces working I moved to your style.  Not sure but I suspect yours will give better performance and memory management, I have very large dataframes.

Comment: @MatthewDoering not sure either about memory management, I would say you don't need to free some space after with this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel we can do

```
s1=df.sort_values('high_temp').drop_duplicates('month',keep='last')
s2=df.sort_values('low_temp').drop_duplicates('month')
df=s1.drop('low_temp',1).merge(s2.drop('high_temp',1),on='month',suffixes=('_high','_low'))
  month week_high  high_temp week_low  low_temp
0   jan       wk2         20      wk1         4
1   feb       wk1         30      wk1        23
```